Sum Dynamic List of Expenses in React
I need to dynamically add and remove a series of expenses in React. The goal will be to subtract the total expenses from the income and display it.
I have have two components in my App:
App -> Accepts and Stores User Income, Displays the Expense Component, Displays the total of income minus expenses
const App = {

const [net_income, setNetIncome] = useState(0)    
const [totalExpense, setTotalExpense] =  useState(0)
const totalSavings = net_income - totalExpense
useEffect(() => setValue(totalSavings))


return(
    
  <div>
        <h4>Income</h4>
        <label>Monthly Income (net) $</label><input type="number"  value={net_income} onChange={(e) => setNetIncome(e.target.value)} onBlur={(e) => setNetIncome(Number(e.target.value).toFixed(2))}></input>
        <h4>Current Expenses</h4>
        <Expenses setSum={setTotalExpense}/>
        
        <p>Total Expenses: ${totalExpense} | Total Savings: ${totalSavings.toFixed(2)}</p>
  </div>  
)

}
Expenses -> Stores the list of individual expense widgets, reports total of all expenses to App, Allows users to add or remove individual expense widgets; on removal, expense should be subtracted from total
function Expenses ({ setSum }) {

const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState([])

function getSum() {
    const values = Object.values(expenses);
    console.table(values)

    const sum = values.reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0);
    console.log(`Setting sum to ${sum}`)
    setSum(sum);
}

// When `expenses` changes call `getSum`
useEffect(() => getSum(), [expenses]);

function removeExpense(removedExpense) {
    console.log(`Removing Expense ${removedExpense}`)
    setExpenses(oldExpenses => { 
        return oldExpenses.filter(oldExpense => oldExpense !== removedExpense)
    })
}

function addExpense(index) {
    console.log(`Adding Expense`)
    setExpenses([
        ...expenses, <Expense key={index} RemoveCallback={removeExpense}/>
    ])
    
    console.table(expenses)
}

const expenseComponents = expenses.map((_, id )=> (<Expense key={id} value={expenses[id]} />))

return(
    <>
        {expenseComponents}
        <Box sx={{display: "flex", alignItems: "center"}}><label>Add Expense</label><img width="25" src="/static/images/plus.png" onClick={addExpense}/></Box>
    </>
)

}
Expense -> Individual expense, stores the expense name and value
function Expense () {
const [expenseName, setExpenseName] = useState("")
const [expenseAmount, setExpenseAmount] = useState(0)



return (
    <div style={{ display:'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <input 
            name='expense'
            placeholder='Expense'
            onChange = {(e) => setExpenseName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input 
            name='amount'
            placeholder='$0.00'
            onChange = {(e) => setExpenseAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
        <img width="25" height="25" src="/static/images/minus.png" onClick={(e) => handleRemove(e.target.index)}/>
    </div>
);

}
Could someone please explain to me not only how to accomplish this, but the thought process behind it? It is entirely unclear to me how I should be passing the data between the discrete components to arrive at the total.
All help is appreciated.

Well you can sum the expenses by using the array reduce method to sum the expenses then you can subtract that from the income... You can use a state hook to store the expenses and update the value as you normally would if you are adding or removing expenses.

Yup, have done all of this. Doesn't work the way I think about it. Clearly I'm misunderstanding something, which is why I'm asking for a deeper explanation.
Thanks!

Here is a rough example that should get you started in the right direction. It's extermely basic but has the fundemental functionality you were looking for. PS: please excuse the random formating, stackblitz mangled it and I wasn't about to fight with it.

Hi Jacob,
Thank you - this is exactly the solution I was looking for. I really appreciate the comments! Super nice of you!
What I'm seeing is that the Expense widget isn't keeping track of its own information - that's the opposite of how I was thinking about it. Understanding there are lots of ways to solve a problem, could you point me to some kind of guidance on how to think about these problems the React way, if its not too much trouble?
Regardless, thanks again!
